# Flutter Android application icon when app is minimized

Tags: android, flutter, icons

I've been trying to find a way to change that icon by many ways but that didn't work - I still get this white android on the blue background.

I tried:

- using `Android Assets Studio` where I configured all assets (app icon and everything else looks good except that minimized icon)
- changing `AndroidManifest.xml` icon and round icons
- using `flutter_launcher_icons` plugin

And everything is without luck. How can I manually change that specific minimized icon?
[image: minimized app icon]

[image: Android Assets Studio]

[image: android xml file]

[image: resources]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, this is only an issue when working in the debugging mode on an emulator. I've tried the same application on the physical mobile device and it had the correct image up there. Perhaps, it's a Flutter bug.

Comment: I thought the same and almost gave up but finally after clearing the app cache and app storage on the emulated device and rebuilding it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

that is regular ic_launcher.png the one under "round" that is selected in picture above.

Comment: But even though I have that `ic_launcher_round.png`, it still shows the 'default' Android one.

Comment: yap it takes ic_launcher and makes it round.

Comment: I assume you didn't understand my question. My question was WHY does the app show a default android round icon even though I've set up my own, custom icon. You said that ic_launcher should be displayed but it's not displaying my ic_launcher.

Answer (score 0):

When using flutter_launcher_icons package, try giving your new icon set a new config name like 'new_launch' and providing image_path and adaptive_icon_background for android.

Running `flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main` in terminal got my icon in the minimized screen as well.

[Here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeD1d.png)

Comment: as I described below, it's only a problem for the debug mode not the release.